# Array of Types in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, types

I am trying to create instances of objects of various types by iterating and checking for validity. I need an array of types so I can do something like this:

```
def tryClasses(in)
    types = [Foo::A, Foo::B, Foo::C]

    types.each do |type|
        a = type.new(in)
        return a != null
     end
end
```

How do I create and array of class types?
Doing it this way I am getting a NoMethodError (undefined method 'A' for Foo)

Comment: how do you want the function to behave? filling the array and generating classes works fine. Do you want it to return the first class where new succeeded?

Comment: I just realized what you mean. Yes, for learning purposes I just want it to return true when it creates a valid instance of A B or C.

Comment: What's `tryClasses(in)` and who's that `end` at the end with?

Comment: Arg- I am learning ruby and can't eyeball terrible syntax mistakes yet.

Comment: Foo::A is just an example. My real task involves Watir::Link, but I'm really pushing my ruby limits.

Comment: @willoller: what language are you coming from? Java? Haskell?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: I'm coming from php and c#. So, yeah, ruby is taking me some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the obvious syntactic errors (e.g. `in` is a reseved word, and `null` is spelled `nil` in Ruby), the code you showed should work just fine as it is, and indeed it does when I copy&paste it into my Ruby installation. This assumes, of course, that the classes `Foo::A`, `Foo::B` and `Foo::C` actually exist. If they don't, then the code obviously cannot possibly work.

It is, however, completely un-Rubyish and violates just about every coding convention in the book:

1. indentation is 2 spaces
2. method names are `snake_case`, not `camelCase`
3. explicitly checking for equality to `nil` is a no-no, simply calling `#nil?` is much preferred
4. `try_classes` isn't exactly an intention-revealing method name
5. and WTF does `in` mean?
6. Rubyists much prefer higher-order methods over explicit looping

Here's a more Rubyish version of the code you wrote:

```
def can_create_object?(*args)
  [Foo::A, Foo::B, Foo::C].none? do |klass|
    klass.new(*args).nil?
  end
end
```

However, note that I am pretty convinced that the whole idea is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: lol okay - you've browbeaten me into reexamining my initial assumptions.  I'll be back with a better question another day!